# INSERT INTO @table, where @table is a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I have run into a little bit of a problem: I want to create a procedure that inserts some rows in a table specified via parameter. So along the code I have reached this point:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc @tableName VARCHAR(30)
AS
    -- ...some code...
    INSERT INTO @tableName VALUES(...some values...)
    -- ...some code...
GO
```

This doesn't work so maybe I'm missing something.

P.S: I'm working in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use variables for constants in a query -- not for identifiers.  So, you need to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'insert into [tablename] values ( . . . )';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[tablename]', quotename(tablename));

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Two points.  First, if you are planning in on passing the table name using a multi-part identifier, then `quotename()` is not appropriate.

More importantly, passing table names around like this is almost never needed in a relational database.  If you find the need to do this, you likely have a problem with your data model.  I would guess that you have multiple tables with the same structure -- and these should be combined into a single table rather than multiple tables.

To handle quotes strings:

```
set @sql = 'insert into [tablename] values (''aaa'', ''bbb'', . . . )';
```

Those are repeated single quotes (`''`), not double quotes (`"`).

Comment: and if after VALUES i have some strings as parameters how should i procede? i want something like set sql = 'insert into [tablename] values ( 'aaa','xxx' )'; but the sql gets intrerruped

Comment: I would suggest checking if table with that name is present in database. Just in case :)

Comment: @Norby . . . You need to double up on the single quotes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have put values ( "aaa","xxx" )' and i get an error: Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.